# XAML : expand expander when an item in the group is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, expander

Is it possible for a expander to check for the IsExpanded Property if an item inside the group of the expander is selected then this expander is expanded so IsExpanded will be true? Because if i set it to true by default all expanders will be expanded at that's not the goal.

```
<controls:CommandListBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                                     Visibility="{Binding IsComponentOrSystemPropertySearch, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                     Grid.Column="2"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResult}"
                                     ToolbarItems="{Binding ToolBarItems}"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle"
                               TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="exp"  IsExpanded="False" Margin="0,0,0,30" >
                                                <Expander.Header >
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="18" Padding="0" Margin="0"/>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                                    <Grid Margin="20 0 0 0" >
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                                                                          Grid.Row="0"
                                                            Content="{Binding Path=Items[0].DisplayRepresentation.Header}"/>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                                                                        Grid.Row="1"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                        </Expander>

                  </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ItemsControl.Resources>
                <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>

                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <DataGridRowsPresenter />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DeluxePropertySearchResult}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DisplayRepresentation}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </controls:CommandListBox>
```

Comment: So you want to set the IsExpanded property of your ```exp``` expander to true if one of the items in its ItemsPresenter is itself expanded?

Comment: exactly but not if the item is expanded just selected inside of the expander because when i refresh all expanders get closed and if i refresh the selected item inside of that expander stays selected but the user has to expand the expander to see it.

Comment: Maybe you can just bind the IsExpanded property to a boolean property in your viewmodel, this way when you refresh your expanders they keep the same view model and keep the same IsExpanded value?

Comment: but then all expanders are expanded an not just the one where i have an selected item and that's not nice if the list has many expanders/groups

Comment: You want the IsExpanded property be bound to from the GroupItem and the GroupItem should be notified of changes in the child collection items IsSelected properties ie when any item is added to the groupitem, you also attach eventhandler to the IPropertyChanged and if the IsSelected state was changed you decide whether the IsExpanded property should be changed to true or false.

Comment: Yes how can that be implemented?

Comment: How can you select items _inside_  an `Expander` when this `Expander` is collapsed?

Comment: Also if you need an expandable list view why not use the `TreeView`?